# Bash - Two processes for one script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ps

I have a shell script, named test.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
ps xc | grep test.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l
vartest=`ps xc | grep test.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l `
echo $vartest
echo "end"
```

The output result is :

```
start
1
2
end
```

So my question is, why are there two test.sh processes running when I call ps using `` (the same happens with $()) and not when I call ps directly? 
How can I get the desired result (1)?

Comment: Reproducible on 4.3.11; no idea what's causing this though.

Comment: Because your line starting with `ps..` itself might appear in the seconds ps call too I guess

Comment: @derHugo : Nope. If I put my ps... line 10 times before the vartest and 10 times after, this line still outputs 1

Comment: And if you complete do it without the direct ps?

Comment: @derHugo It displays 2 when I comment the first ps line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you start a subshell, as with the backticks, bash forks itself, then executes the command you wanted to run.  You then also run a pipeline which causes all of those to be run in their own subshells, so you end up with the "extra" copy of the script that's waiting  for the pipeline to finish so it can gather up the output and return that to the original script.

We'll do a little expermiment using `(...)` to run processes explicitly in subshells and using the `pgrep` command which does `ps | grep "name" | grep -v grep` for us, just showing us the processes that match our string:

```
echo "Start"
(pgrep test.sh)
(pgrep test.sh) | wc -l
(pgrep test.sh | wc -l)
echo "end"
```

which on a run for me produces the output:

```
Start
30885
1
2
end
```

So we can see that running `pgrep test.sh` in a subshell only finds the single instance of test.sh, even when that subshell is part of a pipeline itself.  However, if the subshell contains a pipeline then we get the forked copy of the script waiting for the pipeline to finish

Comment: Could you add a comment explaining what `pgrep test.sh` does, and what the brackets `(foo)` do?

Comment: @Blacksilver `ps` + `grep` = `pgrep`

Comment: I tried creating a file that only does testvar=`sleep 20`. I run the script, and while the script is running (sleeping), I check the process using ps. There is only one test.sh file in this case. So using backticks doesn't always mean new process. Is there another condition to have a subprocess ? (like, is it because I use a pipe ? ). Thanks !

Comment: @ceving, I know, I looked it up in the man pages. For everyone else.

Comment: @user6050469 the key piece is that there has to be a subshell within the subshell, so if you do `testvar=$(sleep 20 | echo)` you'll see the extra, because it's waiting for the output of the pipeline

Comment: @EricRenouf Thanks ! That explains it :)