# Why does "pgrep -f bash" emit two numbers instead of one?

Tags: linux, shell, pid

**When I run this script in shell:**

```
printf "Current bash PID is `pgrep -f bash`\n"
```

**using this command:**

```
$ bash script.sh
```

**I get back this output:**

```
Current bash PID is 5430
24390
```

**Every time I run it, I get a different number:**

```
Current bash PID is 5430
24415
```

**Where is the second line coming from?**

Comment: `pgrep` is finding two copies of bash, and returning both their PIDs with a newline between them. `pgrep` **doesn't** look for the "current" PID; for that, use `$$` or `$BASHPID`.

Comment: As an aside, it would be more appropriate to run `printf 'Current bash PID is %s\n' "$(pgrep -f bash)"`, keeping your data out of your format string; that way data containing `%s` or backslashes is still printed literally. (If you *want* backslashes-escape sequences to be honored, use `%b` instead of `%s`).

Comment: Do I run this `printf 'Current bash PID is %s\n' "$($$ -f bash)"`instead?

Comment: `printf 'Current bash PID is %s\n' "$$"`, rather.

Comment: `  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   5430 pts/1    Ss     0:02 bash` Says here PID is 5430. Using `$$` I get a whole different number. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind that when you run `bash yourscript`, that starts a new copy of bash with a new PID, so `$$` will change each time. If you want the PID of your interactive shell, you can `source yourscript` instead of `bash yourscript` to run the script's contents inside your existing interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use backticks (or the more modern `$(...)` syntax for command substitution), you create a subshell. That's a `fork()`ed-off, independent copy of the shell process which has its own PID, so `pgrep` finds two separate copies of the shell. (Moreover, `pgrep` can be finding copies of bash running on the system completely unrelated to the script at hand).

---

If you want to find the PID of the current copy of bash, you can just look it up directly (`printf` is better practice than `echo` when contents can contain backslashes or if the behavior of `echo -n` or the nonstandard bash extension `echo -e` is needed, but neither of those things is the case here, so `echo` is fine):

```
echo "Current bash PID is $$"
```

Note that even when executed in a subshell, `$$` expands to the PID of the parent shell. With bash 4.0 or newer, you can use `$BASHPID` to look up the current PID even in a subshell.

---

See the related question [Bash - Two processes for one script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759744/bash-two-processes-for-one-script)